# drop-down button type quick menu

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, menu, gmail

I'm essentially looking for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nickbabcock/EA6LS/3/

Another example, but its not a hover menu: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html

But I dont know what its called to get more examples of this type of menu. Its like the facebook "more user info" menu when you hover over a persons name in a status update

Also similar to the top-right facebook user menu, where you access your account info/log out.

Or the gmail checkbox menu.

I'm looking for something that has the option for mouseover and/or click to activate the menu. Some that can cater for images and lists with auto-widths!

Answer (score 0):

Either of these will be configurable for what you want:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ - 
http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#basics

This one looks like what you're looking for but would need some additional tweaking to allow for hover.
http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

Comment: Not sure why you -1'd me.. the answer provided is not what I'm looking for unfortunately :(